# How to return an error from FuturesUnordered?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a set of futures to be run in parallel and if one fails I would like to get the error to return to the caller.

Here is what I have been testing so far:

```
use futures::prelude::*;
use futures::stream::futures_unordered::FuturesUnordered;
use futures::{future, Future};

fn main() {
    let tasks: FuturesUnordered<_> = (1..10).map(|_| async_func(false)).collect();

    let mut runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().expect("Unable to start runtime");
    let res = runtime.block_on(tasks.into_future());

    if let Err(_) = res {
        println!("err");
    }
}

fn async_func(success: bool) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = String> {
    if success {
        future::ok(())
    } else {
        future::err("Error".to_string())
    }
}
```

How can I get the error from any failed futures? Even better would be to stop running any pending futures if a single future fails.

Comment: Note that `main` can return a `Result`. If it is `Err`, the content will be displayed: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55e0f19f3b9540a9aee4b26bcb4fd82b

Answer (score 1):

Your code is *already* returning and handling the error. If you attempted to use the error, the compiler will quickly direct you to the solution:

```
if let Err(e) = res {
    println!("err: {}", e);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `(std::string::String, futures::stream::futures_unordered::FuturesUnordered<impl futures::future::Future>)` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/main.rs:12:29
   |
12 |         println!("err: {}", e);
   |                             ^ `(std::string::String, futures::stream::futures_unordered::FuturesUnordered<impl futures::future::Future>)` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `(std::string::String, futures::stream::futures_unordered::FuturesUnordered<impl futures::future::Future>)`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

The `Err` value is a tuple of your error and the original stream to continue pulling after you have dealt with the error. This is what `Stream::into_future` / [`StreamFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.27/futures/stream/struct.StreamFuture.html) does.

Access the first value in the tuple to get to the error:

```
if let Err((e, _)) = res {
    println!("err: {}", e);
}
```

---

If you want to see all of the values, you could keep polling the stream over and over (but don't do this because it's probably inefficient):

```
let mut f = tasks.into_future();
loop {
    match runtime.block_on(f) {
        Ok((None, _)) => {
            println!("Stream complete");
            break;
        }
        Ok((Some(v), next)) => {
            println!("Success: {:?}", v);
            f = next.into_future();
        }
        Err((e, next)) => {
            println!("Error: {:?}", e);
            f = next.into_future();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When the first item is successful in the FuturesUnordered set, it will not return the error if the next one fails: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e549cbf11a5227cc2d27f609c0180f7

Comment: @James that's the combined contract of `FuturesUnordered` / `Stream` / `into_future`. It will only poll enough to return the first item in the stream. If an error occurs, that's returned first, if a success is first, that's what's returned. In your example, the *failure never occurs* because it's never even polled. It's [more obvious with a non-eager future](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d9a88080921ca5c15379d21f41ebbee).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there an alternative way I can look into rather than FuturesUnordered to achieve what I want?